# Dropping ID of multiindex dataframe if a specific column only includes NaAs for that ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, multi-index

I have a mulitindex dataframe looking somethin like that (but with over 20k rows and around 100 columns):

```
         x1  x2  x3
Time ID
1    1   1   2   NaN
2    1   1   2   3
1    2   1   2   NaN
2    2   1   2   NaN
```

I'd like to drop all IDs whos' columns x3 only contain NaNs but keeping the one that might contain NaNs but also have some actual values. For the above example my desired output would be:

```
         x1  x2  x3
Time ID
1    1   1   2   NaN
2    1   1   2   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `any` on `groupby`:

```
df[df.x3.notnull().groupby('ID').transform('any')]
```

Output:

```
         x1  x2   x3
Time ID             
1    1    1   2  NaN
2    1    1   2  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do `dropna` with `isin`

```
df=df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(1).isin(df.dropna().index.get_level_values(1))]
Out[71]: 
         x1  x2   x3
Time ID             
1    1    1   2  NaN
2    1    1   2  3.0
```

Comment: Thanks @YOBE_S! But how does that only take values of column x3 into account?